# How do I perform Constructor-based dependency injection with Spring using annotations?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-annotations, constructorargument

OK, so if I need to put some primitive values in the constructor, how do I do that?

```
    @Autowired
public CustomBean(String name, @Qualifier("SuperBean") SuperBean superBean) {
    super();
    this.superBean = superBean;
    this.name = name;
}
```

For instance here I am defining that the superBean has the Qualifier "SuperBean", but I'd also like to know how is it possible to use annotations to set the name value here?

I know it's possible with xml configuration, but I want to know how to do this with annotations too:

```
<bean id="CustomXmlBean" class="org.arturas.summerfav.beans.CustomXmlBean">
        <constructor-arg name="name" type="String" value="The Big Custom XML Bean" />
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean id="SuperBean" class="org.arturas.summerfav.beans.SuperBean" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

Well how do I put in values for String, int and other generic types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way to do this:

```
@Component 
public class YourBean { 
    @Autowired
    public YourBean(@Value("${prop1}") String arg1, @Value("${prop2}") String arg2) { 
        // rest of the code
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I searched in google and seeked in the whole chapter 3 IoC of Spring, but didn't manage to find that @Value, I wonder why they haven't included it there, that's just thumbs down for Spring docs...
I used this with @Value("some text"), can you explain me in more detail what "${prop1}" is? is it some value or variable defined somewhere, can you tell me how to use it too?

Comment: @ArturasM, in `${prop1}`, `prop1` is the key defined in a property file ([loaded via standard spring mechanism](http://bharatonjava.wordpress.com/2013/01/25/configuring-and-using-properties-file-in-spring-3/)).

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it now.