# Trouble wiring-in System.in using constructor injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, constructor-injection

I can inject `System.in` using field based injection with no problem:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

@Component
public class Logger implements IReporter {

    @Value("#{T(System).out}")
    private PrintStream output;

    public Logger() {
    }

    public void info(String message) {
        output.println(String.format("[INFO] %s", message));
    }

}
```

But I have trouble doing the same using constructor injection. The code below fails because the bean doesn't have a default constructor:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

@Component
public class Logger implements IReporter {

    private PrintStream output;

    public Logger(@Value("#{T(System).out}") PrintStream output) {
        this.output = output;
    }

    public void info(String message) {
        output.println(String.format("[INFO] %s", message));
    }

}
```

The error is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 

    Error creating bean with name 'logger' defined in file [/User/h2o/Projects/hello-spring/hello-spring-1/target/classes/org.h2o.beans/impl/Logger.class]: 
        Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.h2.beans.impl.Logger]: 
        No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.h2o.beans.impl.Logger.<init>()
```

If I add a default constructor, then `output` won't be wired in and stays `null`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I perform Constructor-based dependency injection with Spring using annotations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117570/how-do-i-perform-constructor-based-dependency-injection-with-spring-using-annota)

Answer (score 0):

Oops! It needed the `@Autowired` constructor:

```
@Component
public class Logger implements IReporter {

    private PrintStream output;

    @Autowired  
    public Logger(@Value("#{T(System).out}") PrintStream output) {
        this.output = output;
    }

    public void info(String message) {
        output.println(String.format("[INFO] %s", message));
    }

}
```